# warnin arrow function array-callback-return on react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
 static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
const { claimList, claimOpenList } = nextProps

const claimsNew = [...claimList]

console.log('getDerivedStateFromProps > claimsList > ', claimList)

claimOpenList.map(item => {
  const value = claimList.find(val => String(val.claimid) === String(item.claimid))
  if (value === undefined) claimsNew.push(item)
})
return {

  claims: claimsNew,
}
```

}

it works and do what is suppoused to do, but i want to get rid of this warning "Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function array-callback-return" it says the problem is on the line `claimOpenList.map(item => {` i really want to learn how to solve this warnings since its not the only place that it appears,i belive that understanding this one im going to be able to figure out the other ones, thanks for your time and help

i have looked another similar problems on stack but they dont seems to be the same as mine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map()` is used to create a new array based on iterating another array. You are only using it to loop over an existing array.

Just change `map()` to `forEach()` which is intended for that purpose

Comment: thanks, this solved the problem